# Fifa 15 on Windows 8, turn on Keyboard only controls

Tags: windows, fifa-15

I recently installed Fifa 15 UT on my Win8 touchscreen laptop via the Windows Store.

I started the game, but sometimes when I'm not pressing any action buttons, only the D-Pad, the character performs a random action, like a lob, which gives away the ball.

So I downloaded Fifa 15 on my Windows 10 Desktop PC via Windows Store, and when I started a game, I found the Keyboard Controls much easier to use.
 But when I went back to my laptop, I could not find how to change the controls to Keyboard only. Any way to change it to Keyboad Only, or fix the random actions issue?